# WebView of fixed size bottom part of App

Tags: android, android-layout

My app is locked on portait mode.  It's basically a ListView of items (unknown length but scrollable) and I want the bottom of the app to be a fixed size Webview.

So thats like:
Top part of app = ListView
Bottom Part of app = Webview

I need the webview to be of fixed size say 200dp and the ListView should get the rest of the space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also just put listview and webview in order of a linearlayout, and set the android:layout_weight="1" in listview

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oritation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ListView
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

`</Linearlayout>`

Comment: Quick tip... I think it is good for performance if you set the height to be 0dip if you are setting weights.

Comment: Oh, thanks! to set height as 0dip when setting weights do makes a better performance, even ADT in ecplise will remind me with it, but I forget it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Like so?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:a="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    a:layout_width="fill_parent"
    a:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <WebView
        a:id="@+id/webView1"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="200dp"
        a:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        a:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ListView
        a:id="@+id/listView1"
        a:layout_width="match_parent"
        a:layout_height="wrap_content"
        a:layout_above="@id/webView1"
        a:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        a:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```